# How to get the Solana unix_timestamp on the front-end (in JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, solana, solana-web3js

Solana Rust smart contracts have access to

```rust
solana_program::clock::Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp
```

which is seconds from epoch (midnight Jan 1st 1970 GMT) but has a significant drift from any real-world time-zone as a product of Solana's slowdowns over time. Many contracts factor in this unix timestamp when calculating reward amounts (notably Step Finance and therefore Gem Farm which reuses the logic). How can I reconstruct this Solana unix timestamp on the front-end in JavaScript without requiring any transaction / wallet signature? Calls to a Solana node RPC are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getBlockTime` endpoint from JSON RPC.  First you'll need the highest slot using the `getSlot`.  That would become:

```
const connection = new Connection('https://api.testnet.solana.com', 'processed');
const slot = await connection.getSlot();
const timestamp = await connection.getBlockTime(slot);
```

More info at https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getblocktime and https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getslot

Comment: This seems to somewhat work, however it seems to usually return a different value (off by a few seconds) than the value of the `unix_timestamp` which always seems to be consistent.

Comment: good point -- since this example uses `'confirmed'`, it will be a little behind.  I'll amend it to use `'processed'`, which should be better